# Snells Law: Does the $k$ vector change on the boundary between mediums?

Tags: optics, waves, boundary-conditions, wavelength

I was using Waves - Berkley Physics Volume III, and in explaining Snell's Law the author claims that as a wave is on the boundary between glass and air (going from glass to air) that the number of wave crests per unit length along the $y$-axis must be equal in both mediums.

I still don't understand this claim and was wondering if anyone could help explain it.

Also the boundary runs along the $y$ axis, ie the boundary is vertical and so is the $y$-axis.

Comment: I think his statement is that the component of the k vector parallel to the boundary, say $k_y$, must stay the same. But $k_x$ and/or $k_z$ will have to change. As an aside, is that volume of the Berkeley Physics series good? AFAIK the E&M volume by Purcell is the real classic (and still in print).

Comment: Yea it's very good. However explanations are short and to the point, which requires a student to do a lot of re reading to understand the whole material, and the notation used is kind of old. Also thanks for the recommendation, ill be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming I've understood your setup correctly it looks like this:

[image: Refraction]

The red line shows the spacing between crests, and the number of crests per unit length is just the reciprocal of this distance. The red line is obviously constant on both sides of the interface because the wavelength otherwise there would be mismatches in the wave amplitude at the boundary i.e. crests on one side wouldn't line up with crests on the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a continuity condition. In simplistic terms, you want crests transmitted as crests and troughs transmitted as troughs. If the locations of the crests on either side of the boundary didn't match, you'd have crests appearing from non-crests. Weird.